# Is there any way to reset a hibernate sequence once created and having data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am creating a sequence for a table. Starting of every financial year I want that sequence to start again from 1  without deleting the contents of the table for which the sequence is being used. I am using Spring Boot for doing all this work. I am using MySQL as database.

I tried to truncate the sequence table and manually enter the next value but I received an error of duplication of primary key.

Comment: is the seuqence a PK?  That is a bad idea to reset sequences once their values are stored in tables.  Use a date or something more appropriate to represent a year.  That's not what sequences are for.  Either way, post a [mcve]

Comment: You can add a separate column to the table like orderNumberInFinancialYear leaving the existing primary key as it is. For the new column you can use a different sequence and reset it when the financial year starts.